# How to save result of regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a string which contains adress of image file:

```
<p><img alt="" src="/upload/images/image.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 500px;" /></p>
```

I wrote regural expression to find this adress. Images always stores in /upload/images/:

```
preg_match("/(\/upload\/images\/).+(.jpg)|(.jpeg)|(.png)|(.bmp)|(.gif)/", $digest['content']);
```

Is there any way to save this adress which was found by preg_match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is, **[read the manual](http://php.net/preg_match)**

> int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, **array &$matches** [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )

**matches**

> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Send it a 3rd parameter and all your matches will be contained in that.

```
preg_match("/(\/upload\/images\/).+(.jpg)|(.jpeg)|(.png)|(.bmp)|(.gif)/", $digest['content'], $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my inattention.